htmlunit Content Security Policy eval is blocked
I wrote a scraper on a javascript heavy website (written in angular) and it works perfectly. But now after a few months I get error
SEVERE: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise)
My suspect is when I check the website using browser and in console, it seems Content Security Policy eval  is blocked
Is there a way to still use com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit or is it selenium the way to go?

There is always a way :-) but maybe sometimes a long one. Please open an issue on github and provide as much information as possible and i will try to help.
